# How can I send an XMLHttpRequest from a Secure Start Point to an Insecure End Point

Tags: javascript, html, http, xmlhttprequest, cors

## Intro

I'm trying to run a CORS web request from our Department's intranet web page to a different department's web service but I'm getting an error. As I'm quite new to this I cannot determine if the cause is due to different protocols.

## Error

When trying to run a CORS request IE11 gives `Access is Denied` while Chrome 52 gives the following:

```
Mixed Content: The page at {MyPage} was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint {ServicePage}. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`
```

## Intention

Create a JS file that attaches an Event Handler to all required `input` elements which contain the `class='contactLookUp'` attribute. This file will be referenced only on our departmental pages located on the intranet, which most are using the `https` protocol. On input change this will send an `XMLHttpRequest` to a different end point, one still within the company intranet but outside our departmental control and which uses the `http` protocol. This will return contacts in the business in JSON format, at which point I will inject some HTML in the page so the user can easily select the required contact.

## URL of pages

The following are the page locations within the intranet. `[name]` refers to the company name and `[Location1]` and `[Location2]` are the different directories.

Start-Point:

`https://[name]01test.[name].abc/[Location1]/HTMLPage1.html`

End-Point:

`http://[name]intranet02.[name].abc/[Location2]/TelephoneDirectory/TelephoneDirectoryService.svc/GetPeople?term=[SearchTerm]`

## Some possible causes

I'm quite new to CORS, jQuery, and Web Development so I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible, but I believe the following may be the cause:

- Mixed Content (The error Chrome gives makes me assume this is the cause)
- CORS not enabled by server (As the servers are out of our department's control I do not want to ask IT if this is enabled or to enable this unless I'm certain the cause isn't mixed content)

## What I've attempted

- I've attempted to change the end-point to `https` but this returns a `404 Page not Found` error

## Script

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open("GET", url, true); // <= Error here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS needs to be supported by the endpoint your webpage is trying to access. If it isn't, it won't be able to respond to your browsers pre-flight check. CORS isn't intended as a way around secure connections though it just allows cross origin requests.

Your browser (correctly) denies access to the resource because https is intended to be a secure connection, and you're trying to get the browser to connect to an insecure resource which in turn opens a security hole.

When you changed your target endpoint to https, you're getting a 404 because the endpoint isn't listening on the default https port 443 (or at all).

You can check to see if the web service is listening on a different port for https, although probably a long shot.

The other option for you is to build a web service that acts as a proxy. Your web app making the XMLHttpRequest would then make that request to your proxy, which in turn makes an insecure http request to the telephone directory service and returns that result to your requesting client (the browser).

Essentially you need to build a bridge.